# Changing root route from different module

Tags: angular

I feel like this should be pretty straight forward, but I can't seem to figure this out.

I have a bunch of root routes, such as `login`, `events`, etc. I decided to create a module for my main menu, `MainMenuModule` that exports a `MainMenuComponent`, and `MainMenuModule` is imported into my root app module.

```
<menu>
    <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
    <a routerLink="/events/">Events</a>
    <a routerLink="/register/">Register</a>
    <a routerLink="/login/">Login</a>
</menu>
```

My root routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { OrgHomeComponent } from './org-home/org-home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: OrgHomeComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

MainMenuModule has no routing; the links that are in the main menu should trigger other parts of the app.

However, when I click on any of the links, the route doesn't change. If I include the same links straight into my root app component, it works fine, which leads me to think it's because it's in a separate module, but that doesn't really make sense to me, as links are bound to exist in nested modules/components.

Is there something I'm missing about how routes/route links work?

I'm generating my skeletons via angular cli if that makes a difference.

Comment: This question needs more info about the problem. "I decided to create a module for my main menu" is that another module inside the root?

Comment: Yes, that'a s module I'm including in the imports of my root module.

Comment: Can you include your router modules please?

Comment: Have your Routing module for main-menu imported in MainMenuModule? As @echonax It'd be much easier to help if you add your code for the routing module for the main menu here

Comment: MainMenuModule doesn't have routing; it should trigger other parts of the app. I added the code for the root module above. Again, maybe I'm not understanding how I should structure routing, but I feel a bit stuck right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope someone will correct me if I'm wrong, but of course, I neglected that since `MainMenuModule` didn't have a routing module, I needed to import `RouterModule` into `MainMenuModule` so it could recognize routes. Adding it to the `MainMenuModule` imports seems to have worked.

Comment: So, it's just because of not importing the module? My bad. Btw, make sure you add the question with all the depended scenarios :)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by adding the quesiton with the depended scenarios? Also, yah, I assumed because `MainMenuModule` was imported into the root module, it could access `RouterModule`. I guess I still have a lot more to learn about Angular than I thought I did.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're trying to implement the feature modules here.

First of all try removing the '/' sign after the path name in the routerlink as below. And, know the difference between adding `routerLink="/something"` and `routerLink="something"`

```
<menu>
    <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
    <a routerLink="/events">Events</a>
    <a routerLink="/register">Register</a>
    <a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
</menu>
```

**Further explanation -**

This is how your routing file should look alike.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { MainMenuComponent} from './path...';
import { ExampleAComponent } from './path..';
import { ExampleBComponent } from './path..';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main-menu',
    component: MainMenuComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'ex-a', component: ExampleAComponent },
      { path: 'ex-b', component: ExampleBComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'path-a', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
```

Make sure your routing module is imported in the MainMenuModule.

Ex-
If the `router-outlet` is in the MainMenuComponent then adding `routerLink="ex-a"` will work for route changes.
Be cautious with **/ - backslashes**

And, then import your MainMenuModule in the root module. (Probably named as AppModule)

If you have been following all these steps it should work fine.

Comment: Ok, I gotta figure this out more, as I prefer trailing slashes. That said, `MainMenuModule` doesn't have routing; I added the code above. Right now, just AppModule, my root app, has routing, though later, other features will have routing as well. The stuff in the MainMenuComponent will end up being routers that will be defined in other parts of the app. Also, I'll try without the trailing slash, but as I mentioned, if I move the links, as is, to the AppComponent in the root, it works fine.

Comment: Did this answer help you solve the problem or you need more help?